# Use CSS in PHP mail()

Tags: php, css, email

I am looking for a way to use CSS in emails sent with PHP's `mail()` function.

I tried this:

```
  $subject = 'test';
     $msg = <<<EOF
    <html>
      <body>
          <style type="text/css">
             ....
          </style>
      </body>
   </html>
EOF;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <test@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
```

But everything I put in the style tag doesn't work in the email. If I print it, I am able to see it working.

Comment: What is in the actual `style` blocks? And what does your HTML look like?

Comment: Considering it's Emails we're talking here, you maybe safer with inline styles. Secondly, See this chart: [**Email CSS Compatibility Chart**](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) (It does look like Gmail Strips out `<style>` tags)

Comment: I don't think you can use `<style>` tags in emails.  I'm pretty sure most (if not all) clients don't let you do this.  You should try using inline `style` attributes on your elements.

Comment: Most mail clients ignore the `<style>` tag. Use inline styles

Comment: Just some friendly advice: when you start dealing with HTML email, you're entering a world of hurt. Most of your problems will come from quirky, broken and incompatible email clients / interfaces and not your back-end code. Carry on :)

Answer (score 0):

Not every mail client accepts every HTML tag. E.g. Gmail ignores `<style>`. See [www.campaignmonitor.com/css/](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for an overview of which client supports what tag. For CSS it's always better to use inline styles like `<span style="...">...</style>`.

Mailchimp has a handy tool to convert your mails to CSS inline styles: [beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css)